# Plot a semantic segmentation using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, image-segmentation

Given an image as a `uint8` `numpy.ndarray` of shape `(H, W, C)` and a set of binary masks (`uint8`) of shape `(H, W)`, where each mask is related to an instance of a class `c` (you could think of a dictionary having the names of the classes as keys and a list of associated masks for that class as values), how can I use Plotly to show a semantic segmentation of the image that shows information about the class of a mask when I hover with the pointer?

This is what I have achieved so far, using OpenCV to create an image to show after applying the masks to the original image (as you can see if I hover I don't get any information about the class since I was not able to add them):

[image: segmentation example, but hovering over a class doesn't show the name of the class]

(in this example **my goal is to add the information `class: keyboard/mouse/monitor` when I hover over one of the colored mask I've added to the image using the binary numpy arrays**)

which I did like this:

```py
def draw_masks(img, masks):
    # here masks is a dict having category names as keys
    # associated to a list of binary masks
    masked_image = img.copy()
    colors = {}

    for cat in masks:
        colors[cat] = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(3,)).tolist()

    for cat in masks:
        for mask in masks[cat]:
            masked_image = np.where(np.repeat(mask[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2),
                                    np.asarray(colors[cat], dtype="uint8"),
                                    masked_image)
    
    masked_image = masked_image.astype(np.uint8)
    return cv2.addWeighted(image, 0.3, masked_image, 0.7, 0)


import plotly.express as px

segmented_image = draw_masks(image, masks)
fig = px.imshow(segmented_image)
fig.show()
```

If I keep this code I would only have to add the class names for each specific `(x,y)` location (I've tried, but haven't been able to do it).

However, if there is a more elegant solution that uses Plotly to directly add the masks to the image (that could manage automatically the colors for example), it would be better. So far, I've been able to plot the masks (and reach a result very similar to the one in the example) using `add_heatmap`, with the problem that the last trace takes up the entire image (since the heatmap considers also the "invisible" locations, signed with a zero).

Comment: you need plotly to call a callback you define. that will need to be given the coordinates by plotly. -- maybe there are more elegant solutions. maybe it supports "polygons" directly.

Comment: I do not understand all that you want to achieve. It seemed to me that you could get what you intend by setting an image as a background and placing a [rectangle](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#rectangle-positioned-relative-to-the-plot--to-the-axis-data) on that image. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @r-beginners , I'm trying to do one of two possible things: either using the image with colored masks shown in the example and adding "on-hover" annotations when the pointer is located on a mask (in the example I'd like to add to "x", "y" and "color" the annotation "class: keyboard"), or, as you suggested setting the image as a background (so without the highlights that you already see in the example that were added using opencv) and draw colored masks (polygons not rectangles) that support the hover labels by default.

Comment: I've looked at the rectangles link and saw that you can make a "path" to draw polygons. That is exactly what I need, but I was hoping there were Figure methods that could draw these polygons from a binary mask, without having me trying to convert it to some kind of polygon format.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz. I will look into this callback solution.

Comment: if you found a solution to this problem, it'd be highly appreciated if you share it. @NicolaFanelli

Comment: Hi @Danial, I haven't found a solution for plotly but I've decided to log segmentations using CometML